# MYSQL time rounding to nearest hour using TIME_FORMAT, 12 hour but incorrectly applies AM to everything

Tags: mysql, time

I am rounding time to the nearest hour using the query below:

```
SELECT post_id, DeliveryDate, TIME_FORMAT(DeliveryTime, '%h:00:00 %p') AS rounded_time FROM `orders` WHERE DeliveryType='delivery' AND DeliveryDate >= CURDATE() - Interval 30 DAY ORDER BY `DeliveryDate`
```

IT correctly rounds everything but applies 'AM' to all results even though most are in PM in the db.

Here is the original db data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V3XJ.png)
How do I get this to correctly read the AM/PM when using rounding like I am?

Comment: This should work. Please provide sample data, current and and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column's `DeliveryTime` is `VARCHAR`, so first you must convert it to `TIME` with [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and then apply the formatting.

If you are using MySql 8.0, this will work:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(DeliveryTime, '%h:%i%p'), '%h:00:00 %p') rounded_time 
FROM orders
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc11a4e7b8c3ba7568e4ad0cfa59f49b).

If you use a previous version, you must concatenate a date part to `DeliveryTime` to convert it to `DATETIME`:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE, ' ', DeliveryTime), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p'), '%h:00:00 %p') rounded_time
FROM orders
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=64b7dcf2fb51e873c7009b351fb4354b).

Note that this code just strips the minutes from the time. It does not actually round to the nearest hour.
But if all your time values are `hh:00` and `hh:30` then it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed it. I am on MYSQL 8 so I accepted that as the answer